# Node.js pipe post request and get response

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe

I have nodeJs rest API server.

It has some controllers for uploading file to another nodeJs server (responsible for uploading the file to AWS bucket).

This is all working fine with the below code, the problem is that I want to catch the response of the pipe and print it to the log.

```
 req.pipe(request.post({ url: url, qs: qs}))
            .pipe(res)
                .on('error', ((err) => {
                    log.error(`getAudioSoundFile:: error: ${err} ${err && err.message}`);
                    return reject(err);
                }))
                .on('response', ((res2) => {
                    log.debug(`========================================`);
                    log.debug(`On response: ${res2['path']}`);
                }))
                .on('finish', ((res1) => {
                    // Update the exam status with question that was done
                    log.debug(`========================================`);
                    log.debug(`On Finish: ${res['path']}`);
                    log.debug(`On Finish: ${res1['path']}`);
                    return resolve(res);
                }))
```

The response returns to the client correctly:

```
{ path: "some path" }
```

But when trying to print to logger I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this, not sure if this is the best practice:

```
req.pipe(request.post({ url: url, qs: qs}))
            .on('data', ((data) => {
                log.debug(`getAudioSoundFile:: Path saved in AWS: ${data.toString()}`);
            }))
            .pipe(res)
                .on('error', ((err) => {
                    log.error(`getAudioSoundFile:: error: ${err} ${err && err.message}`);
                    return reject(err);
                }))
                .on('finish', ((res) => {
                    return resolve(res);
```

posting it here if anyone need it.